# Login-AzureRmAccount fails

Tags: azure-powershell

On calling azure powershell cmdlet Login-AzureRmAccount I'm prompted to enter my email address. I do this and then the message "redirecting you to your organization's sign-page" appears. The sign-in page is then displayed with the error message:

`•Activity ID: 33a3798c-1362-45ad-a03c-c6dcde5f55ff
•Relying party: Microsoft Office 365 Identity Platform
•Error time: Tue, 20 Mar 2018 11:16:25 GMT
•Cookie: enabled
•User agent string: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; Trident/7.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET CLR 3.5.30729)`

Any ideas on how to diagnose what is happening here?

Comment: are you using adfs to login?

Comment: @4c74356b41 Yes. The problem looks similar to this one. [https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/error-signing-in-with-adfs-and-azure-ad/](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/error-signing-in-with-adfs-and-azure-ad/) I'm currently investigating.